# Is there a way to add reminder item to shared list in iCal?

Tags: macos, ical, sharing, reminders

I'm trying to add a reminder to a shared list in iCal, but I do not see the list as an option in neither the "Get Info" window nor in the "Calendar" menu drop down list. This shared list was shared with me in iCloud; I am not the creator, but I do have view/edit privileges. If I log into iCloud.com, I can add the item there. I can also add via iOS. Also, I can see items in the shared list, and I can check them off, but I just can't add to that list. See screenshots below, notice in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUTwF.png) that the shared "To Do" list is missing but can be seen in [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IiUU.png).

Am I missing a setting, doing something wrong, or is this an iCloud issue? I am able to add items in iCal to a shared list *I* created, just not to one that my wife created.

[image: To-do item Get Info]
[image: Reminders sidebar dropdown]

Comment: I don't have a good answer, but have you tried downloading a copy of BusyCal to see if it can work when Apple's calendar cannot? I have found it to be a much more "Pro" calendar and work better with MobileMe and iCloud than the native client which presumably is intentionally kept simple.

Comment: @bmike - Currently running trials for QuickCal and Fantastical. I love the hotkey adds in QuickCal, it's the Quicksilver plugin I always wanted, but Fantastical is much prettier for calendaring/looking at a schedule. Perhaps I'll try BusyCal and add it into the mix.